# Windows can't see partitions made by Linux

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, mbr

I have recently installed Linux on a late-2011 HP Pavilion desktop. It also has Windows on it. I have made changes to the partition table (MBR) in Linux, more specifically I took 256GB from my 1TB Windows install, which I made a 64GB root partition and a 192GB home partition.

When I boot into Linux, everything is sunshine and lollipops. Nothing is wrong with the partition table. On Windows however, it still thinks that the C drive is still 1TB (931GB to be exact) and in Computer Management it continues to believe it is still 1TB.

Look at Chkdsk, Explorer and Computer Management:

[image: Image]]

Now, this worries me because, I don't want my Windows install to be trashed nor my Linux install, but if I go over 675GB (according to GParted) my Linux install would be trashed since Windows doesn't see it.

How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: A mismatched partition table between Linux and Windows is quite puzzling. The only ways I can think of that such a problem might have occurred could lead to serious problems in the future. If you want more help diagnosing this issue, please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out my NTFS volume wasn't shrinked while installing Linux.

Shrinking my C drive fixed the problem and Windows now sees 4 partitions and everything works fine now.

I had to shrink it from 931GB to 675GB, which was the size it was supposted to be according to Linux.

Comment: The very first step to dual boot is to shrink C drive. You should follow that.